# MySQL Запрос / Сортировка

Tags: mysql

Добра! Есть таблица с инфой об изображении, назовем ее images, где существует столбец colors с 10-ю основными цветами с этого изображения. Необходимо реализовать сортировку по релевантности таблицы images в соответствии с выбранным цветом. При загрузке изображения есть массив с количеством цвета

```
array("fff" => "100", "000" => "90", "" => ""....)
```

Насколько я понимаю, нужно сделать еще одну таблицу (например, color), куда заносить id изображения из images, сам цвет и его количество, и потом при выборке склеивать таблицы и сортировать images по color, но при таком раскладе при добавлении 1 записи в images в color летит уже 10 записей на каждый цвет и его количество.  Как будет грамотно организовать это дело? Желательно с примерами.

Comment: Обычная связка 1 к многим. )) Вот только зачем вам хранить цвета картинки?

Comment: Основной контент - картинки,  чтобы их по цвету и сортировать. Если можно простой пример. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, делаешь 3 таблицы:

```
 1. images (id, path)
 2. color (id, name)
 3. images_color (id_images, id_color, count)
```

Запрос нужно? Запрос:

```
SELECT images.path, colors.name, images_color.count
FROM images_color
Left Join images on images_color.id_image=images.id
Left Join colors on images_color.id_color=colors.id
WHERE id_color=ID цвета из запроса берем
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Comment: Да, желательно. )

Comment: Тогда вопрос: входящий параметр это цвет (или много цветов), и на выходе надо получить список картинок, которые содержат данный цвет в порядке убывания по количеству? Пример 100, 80, 60...?

Comment: Один цвет и в порядке убывания по количеству, все верно. )